# Fetching values from firebase based on key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the structure of the database

[image]

I need to fetch all the values of "QNGGvYL7dgde9Oypi9a4IFdAys03"

I have tried this code but it's not working

```
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
    DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = databaseRef.child("bookmarks").equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               vehicleList.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the key you want to get, you don't need a query:

```
DatabaseReference ref = databaseRef.child("bookmarks").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           vehicleList.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errorrs
    }
});
```